# jasperreport report overflow in new page

Tags: jasper-reports

The following document that I am trying to do, when it receives few elements in the subreports works without problems, the following is the view after generating it

[image]

When the subreportes receive several elements to process, the content of the elements overflows of the bands of the report. As shown in the following image

[image]

What I want to achieve is that instead of overflowing, the content that no longer fits, that is displayed in a new page, I tried changing the splitType property from Stretch to Prevent but it does not work, I have little experience with the reports and I do not know Where to approach the problem, is it necessary to use other types of components to achieve my goal? They could explain or advise me how to solve the problem.

I am working on iReport on ubuntu to generate it, if you want to replicate it in Java SE to print it without needing iReport you can do it with the following classes.

**Required Libraries:**

```
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar 
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar 
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
groovy-2.5.6.jar
itext-pdfa-5.5.5.jar
itextpdf-5.5.5.jar
jasperreports-6.0.0.jar
jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0.jar
```

The source files must be saved in the directory `C:\StyledTextReport`

```
chequeReportTest.jrxml
assetBreakdown.jrxml
dueBreakdown.jrxml
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1toBnsWNqrzjF20vuQULKDTSkUSwGEY9g?usp=sharing

**PdfFromXmlFile.java**

```
package org.o7planning.tutorial.javajasperreport;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.jasperturorial.vo.SimpleDataVO;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;

public class PdfFromXmlFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {
        System.out.println("Print...");
        // Compile jrxml file.
           JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                   .compileReport("C:\\StyledTextReport\\chequeReportTest.jrxml");

         System.out.println(" subreports...");
           JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:\\StyledTextReport\\dueBreakdown.jrxml", "C:\\StyledTextReport\\dueBreakdown.jasper");
           JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:\\StyledTextReport\\assetBreakdown.jrxml", "C:\\StyledTextReport\\assetBreakdown.jasper");
           System.out.println("subreports ok");

           // Parameters for report
           Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
           parameters.put("dataSource", "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource@78bfbb1d");
           parameters.put("emisionDate", "2019-03-08");
           parameters.put("beneficiary", "Lia Waters");
           parameters.put("quantity", "100.00000");
           parameters.put("amountinword", "hundred dollars");
           List<SimpleDataVO> assets = new ArrayList<>();
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           assets.add(new SimpleDataVO());
           parameters.put("assets", assets);


           // DataSource
           // This is simple example, no database.
           // then using empty datasource.
           JRDataSource dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();

           JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                   parameters, dataSource);


           // Make sure the output directory exists.
           File outDir = new File("C:/jasperoutput");
           outDir.mkdirs();

           // Export to PDF.
           JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
                   "C:/jasperoutput/chequeReportTest.pdf");

           System.out.println("Done!");

    }

}
```

**SimpleDataVO.java**

```
package com.jasperturorial.vo;
public class SimpleDataVO {

    String value;
    String label;
    String value2;

    public SimpleDataVO() {
        super();
        value = "1";
        label = "account name";
        value2 = "1.0000";
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

I give the credits of the previous class (PdfFromXmlFile) to the excellent tutorial of reports for beginners of this link

```
https://o7planning.org/en/10293/calling-jasper-report-from-java-application
```

As a beginner, any contribution is a great help

Comment: You have spent a fair amount of time to give us an example that we can reproduce (but it would take time for us to setup everything), however probably just a small [mcve] illustrating the issue (presuming that anyone who answers knows how to setup and run jasper) would be better. Anyway I will try to give you some hints in comments (without diving into all of your code).

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is that you are not using the bands correctly, if something is in the footer (the detail band should not use that space), you should use a footer band, hence from Author and below that space is a footer (not a detail band space). I think you just need to redesign the report some, thinking about what stuff goes in which band.

Comment: I'm correcting the report by using the column footer, footer and column header bands, the tips have been very helpful since I did not know where to start and they have clarified the panorama a lot. Everything seems to be going well, I'm even analyzing using other configurations like lastPageFooter if necessary. I will continue reporting and add the corrected report to the question, once it is over.

Comment: I happy to hear and see a developer that put effort into the problem, please also fix the title when you answer, think of somethig that better reflects your problem.